# Meaning of the word "boujee"

Tags: meaning, word-usage, word-choice

[THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=X7xjhouk33w) is a song Bad and Boujee by Migos. I wonder what the word *boujee* means here.
I can't conclude because the verses around it are not so closely related.
Is that girl so great, she is at the top, very rich or something else?
What other word could we use instead of that?

Answer (score 3):

From https://refinery29.com/2017/01/135407/migos-bad-boujee-meaning linked in the comments:

> Now that we have that out of the way, “Boujee” is a bit more complex. Also stylized as bougie, the word is derived from “bourgeois,” an elite demographic defined by a need for luxury and material items. Bougie is true to that definition in a lot of ways. Black bougie folks often pride themselves on going to the best schools and only engaging in activities associated with affluence and elegance. In the most simplistic terms, bougie is the material opposite of “ghetto.”

Comment: How do you pronounce it?

Comment: @dan You can hear it in the song here: https://youtu.be/X7xjhouk33w?t=30s Be warned however that the language is very vulgar. Definitely not "safe for work".

Answer (score 1):

It derives from **bourgeois**, the French word, shortened in some dialects such as African-American speech.

It means upper class and snooty, etc. in that sense.

Comment: How do you pronounce it?

Comment: boo-and then like the gi in Gigi, the girl's name in French: boogi Bourgeois is: boor [like a boor] juwha....something like that. Could do the phonetics but would have to look it all  up.